# How to drop columns from rows with index and iloc

Tags: python, pandas

How to edit the following code to drop a column saved in `rf.index[0]` as str ones using `iloc` and ones using `index`?

```
# This here selects the row with iloc n, now I want to select the column name in rf.index[0] in the same line
df = df.iloc[[n]]

# This here drops the row with index n, now I want to drop the column name in rf.index[0] in the same line
df = df.drop(df.index[n])
```

Comment: `df.drop(df.index[n], axis=1)` Specify an axis.

Comment: Also, the first command would _select_ the given row, not drop it (as you've written)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 1, you'll want to call `df.columns.get_loc` to get the index of the column name in the column list, so you can pass integer indexers to `iloc`:

```
df = df.iloc[n, df.columns.get_loc(rf.index[0])]
```

For part 2, you can't drop both the row and column at the same time, you'll need to chain two `drop` calls. The second one is called on the first axis.

```
df = df.drop(df.index[n])\
       .drop(rf.index[0], axis=1)
```